# How can I used grep to find a file containing 2 strings?

Tags: file, grep, find

I am searching for the definition of a macro in a project containing hundreds of source code files.

I am fairly sure the macros are all defined in a single file.

If I do a `grep -r` search for a single macro, over 1000 hits occur.

I would like to search each file, and find those files containing both macro names.

Can this be done with grep?

For example something like this:

```
grep -r "MACRO1" AND "MACRO2" ./
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
grep -Pzrl "(?s)(MACRO1.+MACRO2\|MACRO2.+MACRO1)" ./
```

- `-P` perl regex
- `-z` changes newline to null character.
- `-r` recursive
- `-l` print only filename
- `(?s)` makes `.` matching newlines
- `MACRO1.+MACRO2` find when MACRO1 is before MACRO2
- `MACRO2.+MACRO1` find when MACRO2 is before MACRO1

Comment: nitpick: `-z` uses null character as separator instead of newline character... so if input file contains null character, it won't read whole file all at once..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
grep -rlZ 'MACRO1' ./ | xargs -0 grep -l 'MACRO2'
```

- `grep -rlZ 'MACRO1' ./` will give filenames containing `MACRO1`

  - `-Z` is to separate filenames with null character
- `xargs -0 grep -l 'MACRO2'` will give filenames containing `MACRO2`

Answer (score 0):

with gnu `grep`:

```
grep -lrZ 'macro1' * |xargs -0 grep -l 'macro2'
```

it will print files names that contains both macros.